# like sql freetext search

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

maybe this is a dumb question.

How do I achieve in sql " like '%test%' using free text ?

I thought contains and free text are equivalent to " like '%test%', plus one get's grammar check, and performance.

In my case I have :

```
select * from ServiceOfferResultIndexed where contains(FirstName,'test')
```

which gives me 18

```
rows.select * from ServiceOfferResultIndexed where FirstName like '%test%'
```

which gives me 229 rows.

thanks for the help.

The DB, is MS SQL 2005. I think it does support the * as postfix. It seams that if I provide '"*test"' the * is considered as a word not a wild card. Test becomes the following word.

Contains will only support "test *", where it looks for all the phrases starting with 'test' followed by any other character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are two different expressions. `LIKE '%test%'` is going to find any row where those four characters are together (e.g. testimonial, or contestant) where `contains` is going to match on words.

I don't know what full text engine you're using but usually wildcards are supported. For example, what happens if you use where `contains(firstame, '*test*')`? You'll have to consult your specific dbms' documentation for wildcards in free text search.